# How to show two equivalent projection in a $C^*$ algebra are not homotopic

Tags: matrices, homotopy-theory, equivalence-relations, c-star-algebras, projection-matrices

> Show that two equivalent projections need not be homotopic. HINT: Let $P=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $Q=\begin{pmatrix}
>         t&\sqrt{t(1-t)}\\\sqrt{t(1-t)}&1-t
>     \end{pmatrix}\in M_2(C[0,1])$ be two projections. Show they're contained in a common $C^*$ subalgebra of $M_2(C[0,1])$ in which they're equivalent but not  homotopic.

My attempt: for $X=\begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{t}&\sqrt{1-t}\\0&0
    \end{pmatrix}$ we have that: $$XX^*=\begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{t}&\sqrt{1-t}\\0&0
    \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{t}&0\\\sqrt{1-t}&0
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1&0\\0&0
    \end{pmatrix}=P$$ and $$X^*X=\begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{t}&0\\\sqrt{1-t}&0
    \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{t}&\sqrt{1-t}\\0&0
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
         t&\sqrt{t(1-t)}\\\sqrt{t(1-t)}&1-t
    \end{pmatrix}=Q $$
so $P,Q\in C^*(X)$ are equivalent. However I'm not sure how to show they're not homotopic as projections in $C^*(X)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure how to show that these are not homotopic, but I think the right $C^*$-subalgebra to start with is $A:=\{f\in C([0,1], M_2): f(1)\in\mathbb{C}\cdot e\}$ , where $e:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.. I could be wrong though

Comment: @alepopoulo110 This is a bigger $C^*$ algebra since in contains $X$, so it suffices to show they're not homotopic in $A$, but why do you think it would be easier there?

Comment: Yes, it is a bigger $C^*$-algebra, but it is easier to understand than $C^*(X)$

Comment: The $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $P$ and $Q$ consists of those $f\in C([0,1], M_2)$ where $f(1) \in \mathbb C e_{1,1}$ and $f(0)$ is diagonal. So one can check that the smallest $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $C([0,1], M_2)$ in which $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent is $A= \{ f\in C([0,1], M_2) : f(1) \in \mathbb C e_{1,1} \}$. But $P$ and $Q$ are clearly homotopic in $A$ (consider the homotopy $H(s)\in A$ which is $P$ for $t\in [s,1]$ and $Q(t+(1-s))$ for $t\in [0,s]$). So the hint doesn't work.

Comment: @JamieGabe Is $H$ necessarily continuous?

Comment: To help you understand the homotopy, let $R$ be the projection in $C([0,2],M_2)$ (larger interval) which is $Q$ on $[0,1]$ and is $P$ on $[1,2]$. Then  $H(s)$ is simply $R$ restricted to the interval $[1-s, 2-s]$, and then reparametrised to be in the $C^\ast$-algebra $A$. Clearly this is continuous in $s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the subalgebra of $C([0, \pi ], \mathbb R)$ formed by the functions $f$ such that $f(0)=f(\pi)\in {\mathbb R}e_{11}$.  Consider
$$
  X(t)=\pmatrix{\cos(t) & 0 \cr \sin(t) & 0}, \quad 0\leq t\leq \pi ,
  $$
and put
$$
  P=X^*X=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0},
  $$
and
$$
  Q=XX^*=\pmatrix{\cos^2(t) & \cos(t)\sin(t) \cr \cos(t)\sin(t) & \sin^2(t)}.
  $$
Clearly $X$ lies in $A$, so both $P$ and $Q$ lie in $A$ and $P\sim Q$.  However $P$ and $Q$ are not homotopically
equivalent for the following reason.

Given any potential homotopy $P_s$ between $P$ and $Q$, every $P_s$ will necessarily satisfy
$$
  \text{rank}(P_s(t))=1, \quad\forall t\in  [0,\pi ].
  $$
On the other hand, for any projection $E$ in $A$ satisfying
$$
  \text{rank}(E(t))=1, \quad\forall t\in  [0,\pi ],
  $$
the set
$$
  \mathcal E =\{(t, v)\in [0, \pi ]\times {\mathbb R}^2:E(t)v=v \}
  $$
is a one-dimensional, locally trivial vector bundle over $[0,\pi ]$.  Since all such vector bundles must be trivial, we are able to
find a continuous nonzero section  $e$ for $\mathcal E$.  This means that
$e(t)$ is a nonzero vector in the range of $E(t)$, for every $t$, which we may assume without loss of generality satisfies  $\|e(t)\|=1$, and
$e(0)=(1,0)$.

Since $E(\pi )=e_{11}$, we must have  $e(\pi )=\pm (1, 0)$, and it is possible to prove that the precise value of $e(\pi )$ is a
homotopy invariant of $E$.

Observing that this invariant  assigns $(1,0)$ to $P$, and $-(1,0)$ to $Q$, we see that $P$ and $Q$ are not homotopic to
each other.

Comment: I think my argument was incorrect for complex C^*-algebras so I have edited adapting it to the real case.  I'm still looking for a complex example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Cuntz algebra $\mathcal{O}_2$ and denote the generators of $\mathcal{O}_2$ by $S_1, S_2\in\mathcal{O}_2$.
Put $p=S_1S_1^*$. Then $p$ and $1$ are equivalent, since we have $p=S_1S_1^*$ and $1=S_1^*S_1$.
However, $1$ and $p$ are not homotopic in the set of projections of $\mathcal{O}_2$. Indeed, assume that $\{p_t\}_{0\leq t\leq 1}$ is a path from $p$ to $1$. Then the value of $\lVert 1-p_t\rVert$ is $0$ or $1$, since $1-p_t$ is a projection. Since $\lVert 1-p_0\rVert=\lVert 1-p\rVert=1$, we have $\lVert 1-p_t\rVert=1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ by the continuity of $\{p_t\}$. Therefore, we obtain $\lim_{t\to 1}p_t\not=1$,
which contradicts to the assumption that $\{p_t\}$ is a path to $1$.

I am sorry that I cannot make use of your hint.

Comment: This is a nice example!

Comment: Yes indeed!  Now I feel bad for having received the bounty with a much less interesting example :-(

Comment: However, is the set of projections a common $C^*$ algebra they are not homotopic in?

Comment: Of course, the set of projections $\mathrm{Proj}(\mathcal{O}_2)$ is much smaller than $\mathcal{O_2}$.

Comment: Very nice example, but are we really using the Cuntz algebra structure? What about a non-unitary isometry in any algebra? Wouldn't the same argument work?

Comment: @alepopoulo110 As you point out, we do not use the Cuntz algebra structure. If $A$ is a C*-algebra and $V\in A$ is a non-unitary isometry (i.e. $V^*V=1$ and $VV^*\not =1$), then $1$ and $VV^*$ are not homotopic but (Murray-von Neumann) equivalent. The proof is same.